# $S(r,s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+r+1)(2k+s+1)}$ for $r>s\geq0$ and even integers $S$ generates $\pi$ or rational values.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

\begin{align}
S(r,s) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} = \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+r+1)(2k+s+1)}
\end{align}
Assuming $r>s\geq 0$ and both $r,s$ even integers.

A few values, using wolfram:

\begin{align}
&S(2,0) = \pi/4-1/2\\
&S(4,0) = 1/6\\
&S(4,2) =  5/6 - \pi/4\\
&S(6,0) = \pi/12-13/90\\
&S(6,2) = 1/30\\
&S(6,4) = \pi/4 - 23/30\\
&S(8,0) = 19/210\\
&S(8,2) = 181/630 - \pi/12
\end{align}

For the rational values of $S(r,s)$ we have:

\begin{align}
S(r,s) = \frac{1}{r-s} \left( \frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{1}{s+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{r-1} \tag{1} \right)
\end{align}

I think for the irrational values must be something similar to $(1)$ except we will have to add $\pi$ after the sum.

What is the general formula for $S$ (or just the formula for irrational values) $?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$S_n(r,s):=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+r+1)(2k+s+1)}$$
for each $n=0,1,2,\ldots$.  Write $r=2p$ and $s=2q$ for some integers $p$ and $q$ such that $p>q\geq 0$.  Thus
$$S_n(2p,2q)=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2(p-q)}\,\left(\frac{1}{2k+2q+1}-\frac{1}{2k+2p+1}\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$S_n(2p,2q)=\frac{1}{2(p-q)}\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+2q+1}-\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+2p+1}\right)\,.$$
Note that, for each nonnegative integer $t$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+2t+1}=(-1)^{t-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}+(-1)^t\,\sum_{k=0}^{n+t}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\,.$$
Hence,
$$S_n(2p,2q)=\small\frac{1}{2(p-q)}\,\left((-1)^{q-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}-(-1)^{p-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\right)+\frac{(-1)^q\,T_{n+q}-(-1)^p\,T_{n+p}}{2(p-q)}\,,$$
where $T_m:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^m\,\dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$ for $m=0,1,2,\ldots$.  Note that $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\,T_m=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.  Ergo,
$$\begin{align}S(2p,2q)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,S_n(2p,2q)\\&=\small\frac{1}{2(p-q)}\,\left((-1)^{q-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}-(-1)^{p-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\right)+\left(\frac{(-1)^q-(-1)^p}{2(p-q)}\right)\,\frac{\pi}{4}\,.\end{align}$$

That is, $S(2p,2q)$ is rational if and only if $p\equiv q\pmod{2}$.  In this case, we have
$$S(2p,2q)=\frac{(-1)^{q}}{2(p-q)}\,\sum_{k=q}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}=\small\frac{1}{2(p-q)}\,\left(\frac{1}{2q+1}-\frac{1}{2q+3}+\frac{1}{2q+5}-\ldots-\frac{1}{2p-1}\right)\,.$$
On the other hand, if $p\not\equiv q\pmod{2}$, we obtain
$$S(2p,2q)=\frac{(-1)^q}{2(p-q)}\,\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\right)^{\vphantom{a^a}}_{\vphantom{a_a}}\right)\,.$$
However, note also that
$$S(2q,2q)=(-1)^q\,\left(C-\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}\right)\,,$$
where $C:=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$ is Catalan's constant.

---

For integers $p\geq q\geq 0$, we also have
$$S_n(2p+1,2q)=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2p-2q+1}\,\left(\frac{1}{2k+2q+1}-\frac{1}{2(k+p+1)}\right)\,.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}S_n(2p+1,2q)&=\small\frac{1}{2p-2q+1}\,\left((-1)^q\,T_{n+q}+(-1)^{q-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}+\frac{(-1)^{p-1}}{2}\,R_{n+p}+\frac{(-1)^p}{2}\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\right)\,,\end{align}$$
where 
$$R_m:=\sum_{k=0}^m\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\,.$$
Because $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\,R_m=\ln(2)$, we get that
$$\begin{align}S(2p+1,2q)&=\small\frac{(-1)^q}{2(2p-2q+1)}\,\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-(-1)^{p-q}\,\ln(2)-2\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}+(-1)^{p-q}\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\right)\,.\end{align}$$

Likewise, for integers $p$ and $q$ with $p>q\geq 0$, we have
$$S_n(2p,2q+1)=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2p-2q-1}\,\left(\frac{1}{2(k+q+1)}-\frac{1}{2k+2p+1}\right)\,.$$
Ergo,
$$\begin{align}S_n(2p,2q+1)&=\small\frac{1}{2p-2q-1}\,\left(\frac{(-1)^q}{2}\,R_{n+q}+\frac{(-1)^{q-1}}{2}\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}+(-1)^{p-1}\,T_{n+p}+(-1)^p\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\right)\,,\end{align}$$
whence
$$S(2p,2q+1)=\small\frac{(-1)^q}{2(2p-2q-1)}\,\left(\ln(2)-(-1)^{p-q}\,\frac{\pi}{2}-\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}+2(-1)^{p-q}\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\right)\,.$$

---

For integers $p>q\geq 0$, we have
$$S_n(2p+1,2q+1)=\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{4(p-q)}\,\left(\frac{1}{k+q+1}-\frac{1}{k+p+1}\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$S_n(2p+1,2q+1)=\frac{1}{4(p-q)}\,\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+q+1}-\sum_{k=0}^n\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+p+1}\right)\,.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}S_n(2p+1,2q+1)&=\small\frac{1}{4(p-q)}\,\left((-1)^{q-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}-(-1)^{p-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\right)+\frac{(-1)^q\,R_{n+q}-(-1)^p\,R_{n+p}}{4(p-q)}\,,\end{align}$$ 
Ergo,
$$\begin{align}S(2p+1,2q+1)&=\small\frac{1}{4(p-q)}\,\left((-1)^{q-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}-(-1)^{p-1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\right)+\left(\frac{(-1)^q-(-1)^p}{4(p-q)}\right)\,\ln(2)\,.\end{align}$$

That is, $S(2p+1,2q+1)$ is rational if and only if $p\equiv q\pmod{2}$.  In this case, we have
$$\begin{align}S(2p+1,2q+1)&=\frac{(-1)^{q}}{4(p-q)}\,\sum_{k=q}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}=\small\frac{1}{4(p-q)}\,\left(\frac{1}{q+1}-\frac{1}{q+2}+\frac{1}{q+3}-\ldots-\frac{1}{p}\right)\,.\end{align}$$
On the other hand, if $p\not\equiv q\pmod{2}$, we obtain
$$\begin{align}S(2p+1,2q+1)&=\frac{(-1)^q}{4(p-q)}\,\left(2\,\ln(2)-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\,\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\right)^{\vphantom{a^a}}_{\vphantom{a_a}}\right)\,.\end{align}$$
However, note also that
$$S(2q+1,2q+1)=\frac{(-1)^q}{4}\,\left(\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\,\sum_{k=0}^{q-1}\,\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right)\,.$$

Comment: Apparently, $$S(r,s)=\frac{1}{2(r-s)}\,\Biggl(\Phi\left(-1,1,\frac{s+1}{2}\right)-\Phi\left(-1,1,\frac{r+1}{2}\right)\Biggr)\,,$$ where $\Phi$ is the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent, which is defined by $$\Phi(z,a,s):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,\frac{z^k}{(k+a)^s}$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|z|<1$, $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0}$, and $s\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\text{Re}(s)>0$.  Apparently, for $\text{Re}(s)>1$, $|z|\leq 1$ is allowed.

Comment: For $\text{Re}(s)>0$ and $\text{Re}(a)>0$, $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}$ is permitted via $$\Phi(z,a,s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\,\int_0^\infty\,\frac{x^{s-1}\,\exp(-ax)}{1-z\,\exp(-x)}\,\text{d}x\,.$$  See https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.14 and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$H_z=\psi(z)+\gamma$$
where $\psi(z)$ is the digamma function. Then
$$H_{(z+1)/2}-H_{z/2}=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+z}$$
$$H_{z+1}=\frac{1}{z}+H_z$$
for $z$ nonzero and not a negative integer ([DLMF 5.7.7](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7.E7), [DLMF 5.5.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E2)). Additionally, if $0<p/q<1$ is a rational number in lowest terms, then
$$H_{p/q}=-\ln q-\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi p}
{q}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{q-1}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi kp}{q}\right)\ln%
\left(2-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k}{q}\right)\right)$$
([DLMF 5.4.19](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.4.E19)).
You should be able to get a closed form for your $S(r,s)$ from there.

Comment: Instead of using such functions isn't there something nicer and simpler like $(1)\:?$ At least to treat the case where $S$ is irrational.